# Angular 4 dynamic routing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to implement a dynamic routing in my angular 4 application. What I trying to do is to push new Route object to Router config. The code looks like

```
@
NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppViewComponent
],
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'appview', component: AppViewComponent }
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ])
],
providers: []})


export class AppModuleShared {
constructor(router: Router, routerModule: RouterModule) {
    console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 1));
    router.config.push({ path: 'new/random/path', component: AppViewComponent });
    router.config.forEach((x, i) => {
        console.log(`${i}: ${JSON.stringify(x, undefined, 1)}`);
    });
}}
```

When the application starts, I want to push new Route Object to config and go to that new path in a constructor. After constructor was executed, in console log I have something like this:

```
5: {
    "path": "new/random/path"
}
```

it looks like the new Route Object was pushed successfully to the config array, but when I trying to enter to this new path application redirect me to the homepage. Could you please describe to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }` takes precedence....

Comment: indeed, I did not notice it... Thank you very much and sorry for my distraction

Comment: did you get how to make dynamic routing in angular ?

Answer (score 3):

Use unshift instead of push

Example: 
router.config.unshift({ path: 'new/random/path', component: AppViewComponent });